# Cross product between two cell arrays

Tags: matlab, for-loop, cross-product

I have the following two vector fields:

```
>> orient

orient = 

    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]
    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]
    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]

>> distance

distance = 

    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]
    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]
    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]
```

and I need to take the cross product of pairwise elements i.e.

```
b = (cross(orient{1,1},distance{1,1}) + cross(orient{1,2},distance{1,2})..... and so on
```

and then reshape to match the dimensions of distance and orient.

Can I do this without using a for loop?

and what about if I have

```
orient{1,1} = 

[1x3 double]

distance = 

        [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]
        [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]
        [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]
```

how do I do

sum1 = (cross(orient{1,1},distance{1,1}) + cross(orient{1,1},distance{1,2}) +...)
sum2 = (cross(orient{1,2},distance{1,1}) + cross(orient{1,2},distance{1,2}) +...)

where each 'sum' is just an iteration of a single orient element, crossed with all the elements of distance, and then those cross products are summed. I would then have:

```
mastersum = sum1 sum2 sum3
            sum4 sum5 sum6
            sum6 sum8 sum9
```

where

```
sum1 = 

[1x3 double]
```

Am I just putting this in a confusing way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) to traverse the cell arrays without a `for`-loop.

For two vector fields (two cell arrays), you should do:

```
crosses = cellfun(@(u, v)cross(u, v)', orient, distance, 'UniformOutput', 0);
b = sum(cell2mat({crosses{:}})', 1)  %# Summing all vectors in all cells
```

A similar procedure for single cell from `orient`, say `orient{1, 2}`, would be:

```
u = orient{1, 2};
crosses = cellfun(@(v)cross(u, v)', distance, 'UniformOutput', 0);
b = sum(cell2mat({crosses{:}})', 1)  %# This command remains the same
```

To get the result for all vectors from `orient` without a `for` loop, do instead:

```
b_func = @(u)sum(cell2mat(cellfun(@(v)cross(u,v)', {distance{:}}, 'Un', 0))', 1);
U = cellfun(b_func, orient, 'UniformOutput', 0)
```

Now `U` is also a cell array (of the same dimensions as `orient`): `U{1, 1}` has the sum of crosses for `orient{1, 1}`, `U{1, 2}` for `orient{1, 2}`, and so on...

Comment: ok i see. that's great. which leads me to another question (please see edit above ^^^^)

Comment: @brucezepplin Ok. By the way, I had a mistake, please see the updated answer

Comment: hi Eitan - yes I have tried both, with the second working and I now realise that what I actually need (and by a similar logic) is to take a single element of orient, and then take the cross product of that with all the elements of distance, then sum into one single vector. Then move on to the next element of orient and do the same....

Comment: let me try the most recent answer out and get my head around it! thanks very much.

Comment: I have accepted the above answer to the question you are referring to. I have looked at your answer to the most recent question. this works great. The only thing left is, how do I automate this process so that i get u11 = orient{1, 1}; u12 = orient{1, 2}; ..... and so on, and then store all the results in an object called U? The individual calculations for each orient work, but i want to iterate over all elements of orient. Thanks very much.